# Map Reduce job design

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Hi I have a large data set like this

```
cp1 -> List(P1,P2,P3)
cp2 -> List(P4,P5,P6)
cp3 -> List(P7,P8,P9)
cp4 -> List(P10,P11,P12)
cp5 -> List(P13,P14,P15)
```

I would like to write a MR job which could yield the following output. So the values would be same for all the keys.

```
p3 -> List(cp1,cp2,cp3,cp4,cp5)
p6 -> List(cp1,cp2,cp3,cp4,cp5)  
p9 -> List(cp1,cp2,cp3,cp4,cp5)
p12 -> List(cp1,cp2,cp3,cp4,cp5)
p15 -> List(cp1,cp2,cp3,cp4,cp5)
```

Can any one help me with the design for this

Thanks
DM

Comment: Please popst your required output properly. They do not have any logic. Only logic is same list for all keys. And why only few keys p3,p6,p9 etc and others missing. is it only yhe last value of list became keys in output?

Comment: Yes it is the last element of the list. And yes it is the same list of keys for all last elements in values . This is step1. Once I have the list built out like this, I will have a step 2 that does some operation on p3 and List(cp1,cp2,cp3,cp4,cp5) and p6 and List(cp1,cp2,cp3,cp4,cp5) etc

Comment: Looks like a homework..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

1. generate output from each map like this: (with any key but same for each line)

   SOMEKEY P3 cp1

   SOMEKEY P6 cp2

   SOMEKEY P9 cp3

   ...
2. In reducer you will get only one key:

   SOMEKEY (P3 cp1) (P6 cp2) (p9 cp3) ..
3. build the list out  the cp1,cp2, cp3. After that its easy to emit keys in your desired format

   p3 -> List(cp1,cp2,cp3,cp4,cp5)

   p6 -> List(cp1,cp2,cp3,cp4,cp5)

   ...

Let me know if you need the code as well.